# Como hacer un salto de linea en una datagridview c# cuando el texto es muy largo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gridview

[image]

Tengo este proyecto, ven que como la descripción es muy larga muestra los `...` Lo que quiero saber es que como dar un salto de linea cuando el `string` supera el ancho de la columna. Gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, como carcas la información al dgv? intentaste usar `Environment.NewLine` ?

Comment: Cargo los datos por su DataSource y a ese DataSource le paso una lista de objetos por parámetro